# Display Sinhalese letters in HTML

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

How to display Sinhalese letter in HTML?

For example,

```
<html>
   <body>
     <p>විද්‍යා දදාති විනයං</p>
   <body>
<html>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes; that will just work.

Comment: @SLaks is it possible for every browser or every computer?

Comment: You will have to set the font face that supports your Sinhalese letters manually ..See my answer..

Comment: This will just work as long as you use `<meta charset="utf-8">` or configure the web server correctly, _and_ save the document as UTF-8. To avoid mojibake when either of those things go wrong, you can use HTML character references. Here’s a tool that generates them for you based on your input: https://mothereff.in/html-entities#%E0%B7%80%E0%B7%92%E0%B6%AF%E0%B7%8A%E2%80%8D%E0%B6%BA%E0%B7%8F%20%E0%B6%AF%E0%B6%AF%E0%B7%8F%E0%B6%AD%E0%B7%92%20%E0%B7%80%E0%B7%92%E0%B6%B1%E0%B6%BA%E0%B6%82

Answer (score 11):

In your HTML document you shoud use

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

in your head tag.

You can also check how your site looks like on services like, for example, [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your web page's head tag as **Бранко Пејић** mentioned in his answer.

Otherwise you can use [SETTdeco](http://settdeco.bhasha.lk/index.php). It enables your Sinhala website readable by any computer without depending on user's Sinhala support.

Answer (score 0):

In your **CSS**, Specify a font with a name,for eg, "myCustomFont", and specify the URL where it can be found:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myCustomFont;
    src: url(your_font.woff);
}
```

and later, in your css, wherever you want to set the font, set it like,

```
font-family:myCustomFont;
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)